# Reload a div with jquery, but not with .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to reload a div on a page on click. So far I have this:

```
<div id="next"><a id="nextC" href="#">NEXT TESTIMONIAL</a></div><!-- END #next -->
```

And the js

```
$('#nextC').click(function(){
    $('#atestimonial').load('/ #atestimonial');
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

I am using wordpress and I have a method sorted for pulling data into the div atestimonial. All I need to do is refresh it on click, doesnt matter about loading a page in.

Can this be done? All I want to do is refresh a div, nothing more.

Comment: Why do you _not_ want to use `load()`? If it's simply because it's not working... I can point out a couple of mistakes.

Comment: I dont want to load  data into the div, the div  handles that when its loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are proposing is not possible with the page as you have currently designed.  In order to have just that segment of the page reload, you will need to break out that div into a new URL that returns only the content you want plugged into that section.

Once that's done, jQuery can reload just that section.

Comment: Thank you for the response :) I will have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This could work to reload #next:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'yourpage.html',
  success: function(data)
  {
    var new_div = $("#next", $(data)).html();
    $('#next').html(new_div);
  }
});
```

Comment: I just literally need to refresh the div.

Comment: It does refresh the div. You can also refresh the div you are clicking on using `$('#click_next').load('test.html');`

Comment: The div has php inside it to randomise a post to display, so reloading the div will automatically update its contents, does that make sense or have i missed it totally?

Comment: You missed it...check my answer.

Comment: Ah, so the problem is that he can only load the whole page but needs only the div? I could do that...

Answer (score -1):

You need to initialize the `evt` variable, and you should have spaces in your URLs.

```
$('#nextC').click(function(evt){
    $('#atestimonial').load('/#atestimonial');
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Note: ["*Loading Page Fragments*"](http://api.jquery.com/load/). That's likely not a URL fragment, but an id selector.